# Как узнать, какие признаки влияют на результат?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Есть данные

```
df = pd.read_csv("X_train.csv")
```

Проделал xgBoost, леса и узнал "ценные признаки".

Мой код получения важных признаков с помощью буста:

```
X,y = df.drop('class', axis=1), df['class'].copy()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)
d_train = xgboost.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
d_test = xgboost.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)

params = {
    "eta": 0.01,
    "objective": "binary:logistic",
    "subsample": 0.5,
    "base_score": np.mean(y_train),
    "eval_metric": "logloss"
}
model = xgboost.train(params, d_train, 1000, evals = [(d_test, "test")], verbose_eval=100, early_stopping_rounds=20)

xgboost.plot_importance(model, max_num_features = 10)
```

Но у меня значения на выходе 0 и 1, как узнать, какие признаки (или какое значение), к примеру, больше всего влияют на то, что на выходе окажется1?

Comment: xgboost.feature_importance_  пробовал?

Comment: @KirillFedyanin, можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, как его применять? Я обучил данные на xgbclassifier, что мне сделать дальше?

Comment: У тебя есть модель классификатора, пусть называется model. У неё есть аттрибут, прям на неё вызови `model.feature_importances_`, он должен вернуть значения.

Comment: Он возвращает, я даже могу построить график, который показывает какие признаки влияют, но мне нужна конкретика. То есть, как узнать, какой признак больше влияет на 0, а какой на 1? @KirillFedyanin 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1258209/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-xgboost
Картинка, как в этом вопросе.

Comment: Вот вам пачка пакетов для интерпретации важности фич, это не такая простая тема https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/03/6-python-libraries-interpret-machine-learning-models/

Comment: Если хотите легко интерпретировать импакт фич, то стройте логистическую регрессию, и смотрите у неё коэффициенты, там они напрямую будут показывать какая фича на сколько умножается )

Comment: Спасибо, буду думать